# Mapping Json to object in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I get a response from the server, lets say in the following format:

```
  {
    //Array of models
        "A_Key" : [
                    {
                      "B_data" : ""
                    }
                  ]
        //dictionary 
        "A_Key_2" : {
                       "C_data" : ""
                    }
        "A_Key_3" : "0"
        "A_Key_4" : 0
    }
```

Now I'm trying to create a model for the above response (I don't want to use any pod or library).

So what I do is:

```
class A{

     let A_Key : Array<B>!
     let A_Key_2 : C!
     let A_Key_3 : String!
     let A_Key_4 : Int!

     init(withDictionary dict:Dictionary<String, Any>){

          self.A_Key = A.getArrayOfModel(fromArrayDictionary:dict["A_Key"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>) 
          self.A_Key_2 = C(withDictionary : dict["A_Key_2"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
          self.A_Key_3 = dict["A_Key_3"] as? String ?? ""
          self.A_Key_4 = dict["A_Key_4"] as? Int ?? 0
     }

     class func getArrayOfModel(fromArrayDictionary array:[Dictionary<String, Any>]){
         var tempArray = [B]()

         for dict in array{

             tempArray.append(B(withDictionary: dict))
         }

         return tempArray
     }
}
```

Assume there are classes B and C with appropriate init methods. Something similar to this compiles properly and all the iterations occur without any crash, so i'm assuming that this will work.

Now my query is, is this the best way to initialize the object in swift with a dictionary? As I'm concerned about a scenario in which the API responds with a `nil` value for any of `"A_Key"` (It will cause a crash i believe)?

**OR**

Is the following the **proper** way to map a json to an object in swift?
If it is, isn't it a bit tedious to check every value for nil? As the number of checks will keep increasing with having optional `init` methods for all nested models?

```
init(withDictionary dict:Dictionary<String, Any>){

      if let a_key_3 = dict["A_Key_3"] as? String{
           self.A_Key_3 = a_key_3
      }
}
```

Comment: Found answer? Same issue

Comment: The best way i've found is to do: `self.A_Key_3 = dict["A_Key_3"] as? String ?? ""` and if there are nested models, you may use optionals as return values for their `init` methods or return empty objects depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Sounds like good solution. Did you created an Extension for each json>model process, or made a generic type?

Comment: Well I'm sorry but i did neither of these things and just parsed the model manually from the API response in each class for each model (The responses in my case were never complex so never really thought about it and now that I am, I think it would need a better/more free mind than mine to do it :) ). I would love it if you could link some documents/samples so that I can get a better understanding :3